# How to avoid repetition of categorical variables while plotting a column chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, repeat

https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/netflix-shows-and-movies-exploratory-analysis/notebook 
contains the data set. (File size - 2.13 MB).

I am trying to plot the top twenty category of contents that are provided by Netflix.

The code that I have tried is as follows,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)    

net_flix <- read.csv("netflix_titles_nov_2019.csv")

net_flix %>% separate_rows(listed_in, sep = ",")%>%
    count(listed_in)%>%
    slice_max(n, n = 20)%>%
    ggplot(aes(y = fct_reorder(listed_in, n), x = n))+
    geom_col()
```

The resultant output is as follows,
[Top 20 categories of shows on Netflix]

[image]

As it can be seen from the graph that there are a lot categories like Dramas, Comedies, International TV Shows are appearing in multiple positions.

The expected output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Can you give a hint on how the data looks like after slice_max? Or in general, how it looks like? This would help (you) a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO, I think you messed up your strings with spaces, also try to follow the ggplot convention on the grammar of graphics

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

net_flix <- read_csv("netflix_titles.csv")

net_flix %>%
  separate_rows(listed_in, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(listed_in = listed_in %>% str_squish()) %>%
  count(listed_in) %>%
  top_n(20, wt = n) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(listed_in, n), y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. str_squish() function is something new that I learnt today.